# Transaction is stuck pending but not available to be cancelled in MyEtherWallet

Tags: metamask

My transaction has been stuck pending for 4 days now, but I can't even cancel it on MyEtherWallet as it is showing up as "Transaction Not Found" on their check transaction page. https://etherscan.io/tx/0xc6948ac8972de3e676b0dc112151b8d1505c6fb86c50c289876ffa5ee4a183e9

It's blocking all of my Metamask (It has a 'Warning - There was a problem resubmitting this transaction' flag on it) and the rest of my funds are stuck as well as I can't even withdraw from it. I made a mistake and made the transaction send 1.2 Eth to myself when I only had 1.1 in the wallet. Is there any way to fix this or are all my funds stuck in limbo forever? Thanks for any input.

Comment: Make another transaction to yourself with the same nonce, and a higher gasprice, with the correct amount.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted by Raghav Sood, you will need to send another txn to yourself with the same nonce (in your case 17). It seems as though you may have attempted this but the nonce of the txn is 18 thus yielding no resolution.

Here is what you need to do:

- Go to https://www.myetherwallet.com/#offline-transaction
- In Step 1, put your address (the one with stuck transaction)
- In Step 2, same address for the 'to Address', 0.001 (or some arbitrary small amount) for the amount, 21000 for gas limit, 8 gwei (high end of current gas price at time of this writing as per https://ethgasstation.info/ + make sure you select gwei not wei). For nonce, put 17, and for data leave it blank. See attached img if this is unclear.
- Connect with metamask, generate the transaction, sign and send it. This should clear up the pending txns.

Lastly, the gas prices for both your txns that are stuck are way too high hence the issue. Hope this helps

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your patience and help! Love the ETH community :O